# chrome issue with :focus-visible? (shows focus-visible styles on normal mouse focus)

Tags: css, google-chrome, focus, accessibility

Accordingly to the example on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible (under basic example), clicking the input with the placeholder ":focus-visible only" with my mouse should not show the orange outline styles – but it does.
Caniuse.com tells me, my chrome version supports :focus-visible.

Any hints?

Answer (score 9):

The [working draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-focus-visible-pseudo) states that browsers manufacturers are free to choose their own criteria for matching `:focus-visible` as opposed to just regular old `:focus`, but  the spec does recommend several suggestions to be used as a starting point, including this:

> Any element which supports keyboard input (such as an input element...) should always match `:focus-visible` when focused.

To me, this says that ALL input elements should always match `:focus-visible`.

In the example that you referenced, you'll notice that the button behavior is as expected. If you click the button with a mouse, it does not match `:focus-visible`, but if you select it with keyboard navigation, then it does.

Comment: Ah now I understand why my inputs are still showing an outline even though I'm using this example: https://css-tricks.com/the-focus-visible-trick/

Comment: Did something change? In the MDN example on Chrome, the CSS is activated no matter if I tab to the element or click it.

Comment: My understanding is that it will continue to show focus if you click inside an `input` or a `select`, but with something like a `button` or an HTML link, you shouldn't see the focus ring after clicking on it. That's the point of `focus-visible`.

Answer (score 0):

The css works for me

For desktop

```
.momsType:focus-visible{
 outline:none!important;
}
```

For mobile

```
.momsType:focus{
outline:none!important;
```

}

Comment: Definitely not the accessible way of doing it, but this does work for my scenario lol, thanks

Comment: Please don't hide the focus indicator. It's there for a reason. Take the time to style it well, integrate it with your color-palette, and it won't look terrible.  https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/focus-visible.html