# React-select: How to display the outline only when using keyboard navigation?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

For a better UX, I am trying to display an outline on the select, when the element is focused, but only when using keyboard navigation (and not displaying it on mouse click).

Using the pseudo-class `:focus-visible` on the `control` styles, when it is focused, does not work, because the element that has the focus is an internal input (dummy input), and not the `control` div, that is the outer element and the one that needs to display the outline. Applying a tabindex=0 to the control div does not work either, because the dropdown will not work when using the keyboard either.
The pseudo-class `:focus-within` does not serve the purpose also, because it would get outlined for both keyboard navigation and mouse click, which is not the intended.

Control styles (not getting the expected result, because outline is being displayed also on mouse clicking):

```
const customStyle = {
    control: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        height: '4.8rem',
        border: '0.1rem solid gray',
        fontSize: '1.4rem',
        outline: 'unset',
        ...(state.isFocused && {
            ':focus-within': {
                outline: '5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color',
            },
        }),
    }),
};
```

[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cScOR.png)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: So I was about to post an answer that allows you to use  `:has()` together with `:focus-visible`. However, for text fields, browsers consider it `:focus-visible` anyway even if they used their mouse to click on it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66109577/1086398 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76123040/input-fields-adding-focus-visible-on-click. It's worth noting this is because it's considered desirable for accessibility reasons. I think probably you don't want to fight this. The input fields are expected to have visible focus styles, even if clicked on. Hence the focus-visible spec.

Comment: Here's the attempt to use `:focus-visible` with `:has()` to emulate a `:focus-visible-within` basically. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/youthful-wave-9fmynm. But as you can see, browsers don't distinguish even with `:focus-visible` between keyboard/mouse on text fields, and that's by design. Tested on chrome, but the spec allows browsers some leeway, so results may vary.

Comment: In short, I guess the standard therefore actually considers the default behaviour of focus-visible on textfields the better UX (considering accessibility also). Its a lot to do with knowing what field you are typing on in mobile where you have virtual keyboard.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense and I agree with what you've said. I was just trying to follow the requirements we have. 
I've also tried the `:has()`, but it didn't work, for the reason you mentioned. Thank you so much for all the information you've shared.